# DbContext not acting as PerWebRequest

Tags: .net, entity-framework, castle-windsor

I'm using Entity Framework and Castle Windsor in an ASP.Net Web API project.

All services, (including the context implementation) etc. are configured with a PerWebRequest lifestyle.  I find however that the context is reused in some instances.  This results in stale updates, which of course is not acceptable.

To add to the confusion, this happens in a specific environment only - debugging, running locally etc does not result in this :(

Not at liberty to share much code, but would appreciate it if anyone has some pointers regarding possibilities regarding this...

Answer (score 1):

This was a non-issue.  The framework maintained a list of contexts to be used on the same thread which of course with clashed (and overwrote) the Castle Windsor config..

Answer (score 0):

I think problem might be your dependency injection choice. In general in a web app, you want to get database objects once per request cycle.
You might want to look in your ConfigureServices Method, in the startup class of your project, and use the addScoped dependency Injection, like so

```
services.AddScoped<NameofRepository, INameofinterface>()
```

that should do the trick. Hope that works for you. Good luck